# Getting several captions or titles within a Matlab legend

Tags: matlab, legend

I have the following script for producing a kind of scatter plot for several experiments. 
The experiments gave two results, on the one hand the vector `s` on the other hand the vectors `C2007`, `C2012`, `O2012` and `O2015`. These 4 vectors show different times of the exerpiments. The exerpiments itself are labeled as `test1`, `test2`, `test3` and so on in the cell`n`.

The following image shows the output from the script:

[image: Too long legend]

Two things are the problem: On the one hand the legend is too long, but using [Columnlegend](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27389-simonhenin-columnlegend) uses too much space. On the other hand the strings like "test1, "test2" etc. are repeated and not categorized under the used shape which stands for the different times (like `C2007, C2012, O2012, O2015`). Therefore it'd be nice if there would be a possibility to make it more obvious that the following points in the legend belong to the vector. To show what I really want to have I made a sketch with Paint:

First possibility:

[image: Still long legend]

This would solve the problem that the shapes are not categorized but still the legend is too long.

Therefore a completly different approach would be too use a shape which is not in the graph to show which color belongs to which test and then just show which shape belongs to which experiment date, again a small draft with Paint to show what I have imagined to do:

[image]

Sadly, I do not know how to achieve this kind of behaviour in this context, such as having specific colors (from the color vector) and specific shapes. Any help is really appreciated

```
close all;

s = [67,3,7,21,2,58,19,5]
colors = [0 0 0; 1 0 0 ;1 0 0.5; 1 0 1; 1 0.5 0; 1 0.5 0.5; 1 0.7 0; 0.7 0.7 0.5];
n = {'test1','test2','test3', 'test4', 'test5','test6','test7', 'test8'}

C2007 = [1.8, NaN, 7.2,3.8,2.44,2.1,7,NaN];
C2012 = [NaN, 6, 5.9, 2.5, NaN, 5.8, 8.1, NaN];
O2012 = [4,9.5,8.8, NaN, NaN, 1.2,4.5, NaN];
O2015 = [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 2.8 4.4, 7.1];

figure;

for i=1:length(s)
   hplot1 = plot(s(i),C2007(i),'*','LineWidth',100,'Color',colors(i,:),'DisplayName',char(n(i)));
   legOBJ1 = legend('-DynamicLegend')  
   hold all;
end


for i=1:length(s)
   hplot2 = plot(s(i),C2012(i),'+','LineWidth',100,'Color',colors(i,:),'DisplayName',char(n(i)));
   legend('-DynamicLegend')
end


for i=1:length(s)
   hplot3 = plot(s(i),O2012(i),'o','LineWidth',100,'Color',colors(i,:),'DisplayName',char(n(i)));
   legend('-DynamicLegend')
end


for i=1:length(s)
   hplot4 = plot(s(i),O2015(i),'^','LineWidth',100,'Color',colors(i,:),'DisplayName',char(n(i)));
   legend('-DynamicLegend')
end

grid on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will provide a hackish way to achieve the second, better point.

To do so, points were plotted with the wanted features outside the shown figure. For making a caption the color of the line was set white , so one is not able to see it in the legend.

```
close all;

s = [67,3,7,21,2,58,19,5]
colors = [0 0 0; 1 0 0 ;1 0 0.5; 1 0 1; 1 0.5 0; 1 0.5 0.5; 1 0.7 0; 0.7 0.7 0.5];
n = {'test1','test2','test3', 'test4', 'test5','test6','test7', 'test8'}

C2007 = [1.8, NaN, 7.2,3.8,2.44,2.1,7,NaN];
C2012 = [NaN, 6, 5.9, 2.5, NaN, 5.8, 8.1, NaN];
O2012 = [4,9.5,8.8, NaN, NaN, 1.2,4.5, NaN];
O2015 = [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 2.8 4.4, 7.1];

figure;

for i=1:length(s)
   hplot1 = plot(s(i),C2007(i),'*','LineWidth',100,'Color',colors(i,:)); 
   hold on;
end


for i=1:length(s)
   hplot2 = plot(s(i),C2012(i),'+','LineWidth',100,'Color',colors(i,:));
end


for i=1:length(s)
   hplot3 = plot(s(i),O2012(i),'o','LineWidth',100,'Color',colors(i,:));

end


for i=1:length(s)
   hplot4 = plot(s(i),O2015(i),'^','LineWidth',100,'Color',colors(i,:));

end

grid on

%Just stupid plots for overview
h1 = plot(-5,-5,'Color',[1 1 1]) %white dot, so that it will not be shown on
                                 %legend
h2 = plot(-5,-5,'*','LineWidth',100,'Color',[0.5 0.5 0.5]);
h3 = plot(-5,0,'+','LineWidth',100,'Color',[0.5 0.5 0.5]);
h4 = plot(-5,-5,'o','LineWidth',100,'Color',[0.5 0.5 0.5]);
h5 = plot(-5,-5,'^','LineWidth',100,'Color',[0.5 0.5 0.5]);
h6 = plot(-5,-5,'Color',[1 1 1])

for i=1:length(colors)
    hh(i) = plot(0,0,'-','Color',colors(i,:),'LineWidth',10);
end

%set boundaries to not show hack
xlim([0 100]);
ylim([0 12]);
legend([h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,hh(1),hh(2),hh(3),hh(4),hh(5),hh(6),hh(7),hh(8)],{'Timing:','C2007','C2012','O2012','O2015','Tests: ', 'test1','test2','test3', 'test4', 'test5','test6','test7', 'test8'})
```